# USB serial port no longer detected after successful upload

Tags: serial, arduino-micro

I successfully uploaded a sketch to my Arduino Micro using the USB serial port but if I try to change the sketch that port is not available. The sketch I uploaded on the Micro runs fine when I plug in the USB cable. The ports shown are /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port and /dev/cu.wlan-debug. If I plug in a different chip the port is there. What would cause it to disappear for the Micro?

Comment: You are probably encountering a very common problem which is already answered on here. Does your non-working Arduino appear in your USB hardware list briefly after reset?

Comment: You are simply running a sketch that doesn't create and expose a serial port to the computer.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means but more importantly, what can I do to be able to upload new sketches (and avoid this issue in the future)?

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed by following suggestion from namakada81 "Open an empty arduino sketch, select the pro micro and no port, click upload and as soon as the ide says "uploading" reset the arduino

Comment: Who is namakada81?

Comment: All I know is that someone with this username posted this solution on reddit 3 years ago https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/cliro2/how_to_reset_arduino_pro_micro_bootloader/